# Spring boot validation annotation not working for Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I got a simple data class for Kotlin

```
data class Person(val name: String, @get: Min(18) val age: Int)
```

I actually build this class from a CSV file and I read the CSV using apache CSV parser. Even I have some data which is less than 18 for `age` field, the test still passed no error.

Looks like this annotation is not working for Kotlin?

Comment: did your validation api enabled by spring boot?

Answer (score 3):

You're currently annotating the constructor parameter with the `Min` annotation - I believe you should annotate the field instead, with a [use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) like this:

```
data class Person(val name: String, @field:Min(18) val age: Int)
```

Comment: Even I change to field it's still not working, never take effect.

Comment: Does it work if you're using a Java class? Maybe it's a problem in the configuration of validation overall instead of with disk specific annotation.

Comment: Do i need to do extra configuration for the validation to be working?

Comment: This issue is only with data-classes, with normal classes it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the annotation`@Validated` to the class (might just work for spring beans though).  These annotations do not prevent the value being set they simply allow getting a `BindingResult` with a list of validation errors from an existing instance.  If you need to prevent a value being set you can use a custom delegate.

```
 val age: Int by MyDelegates.min(18)
```